# What are the leading FHE schemes?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I'm trying to understand the current context for fully homomorphic encryption. What are the most influential papers that are the basis for the most close-to-practical techniques today?

Of course Gentry's original paper is the most influential, but it is far from practical. A 2011 paper I see that appears to achieve much better performance (also by Gentry) is https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/277.pdf. What other papers published in the last 7 years are worth reading? (I would prefer papers with a post-quantum context in mind).

Comment: Are you talking about theoretical constructions or concrete implementations?

Comment: @FlorianBourse Both. But most papers on implementation are based on theoretical papers so theoretical constructions may be better to start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In short**

BGV (the one you linked), FV and GSW.

**More details**

The scheme you have linked is known as BGV and I would say that it is the most important. There is a public implementation on [Github](https://github.com/shaih/HElib).
If the application can run in parallel, then BGV is probably the best current choice, because its plaintext space can be view as a product of rings, which gives the user the ability to encrypt several values in a single ciphertext. Then, a single homomorphic operation is actually equivalent to several plaintext operation in parallel.

The FV is another scheme with that feature and is the one that [SEAL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/simple-encrypted-arithmetic-library/#!documentation) implements now.

If the application can't take advantage of the parallelism, then, I think the best choice nowadays is the so called [FHE over the Torus](https://github.com/tfhe/tfhe), or TFHE.

Since you asked for influential papers, it is worth noting that TFHE is based on [FHEW, by Miccianco](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-46800-5_24), which is based on [a paper by Sheriff Peikert](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/094.pdf), which is based on (this highly influential paper) [GSW](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/340), again by Gentry.

Also, [YASHE](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/075) had an efficient version that was implemented by SEAL before, but it turned out to be insecure.

Comment: "If the application can't take advantage of the parallelism, then, I think the best choice nowadays is the so called FHE over the Torus, or TFHE." <-- Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: @cygnusv the cost of one homomophic operation plus refreshing the ciphertext (the bootstrapping) is much more expensive in BGV. As far as I know, TFHE has the best cost per homomorphic binary operation plus refreshing.  However, one operation in BGV can act in parallel on several plaintexts if we pack them on a single ciphertext. Therefore, the total cost to perfom some task homomorphically can still be smaller using BGV *if* we are able to exploit all that parallelism.

Comment: @cygnusv This is what authors claim, for instance, in minute 33 of this presentation in ASIACRYPT:  https://youtu.be/A-z4kWfSwQk?t=33m

Comment: @HilderVitorLimaPereira Thank you. Can you point to the FV paper?

Comment: @JosephJohnston  sure. This is the link to the original FV: https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/144   but notice that SEAL implements a modified version, as it is explained in its user manual.

Comment: In addition to the ones mentioned I'd suggest adding the CKKS (Cheon-Kim-Kim-Song) scheme. It allows homomorphic calculations on real and complex numbers, but only yields approximate results. It's your best choice if you try to e.g. train a neuronal network with encrypted data. It's also implemented in Microsofts SEAL (in addition to (B)FV).